# Dependency injection - how to improve constructor with many arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm new to Spring and recently noticed that using `@Autowired` in class fields is discouraged. Instead, the use of constructors is recommended for dependency injection (DI).

The problem is that I have defined a bean that requires access to many repositories. Originally, the bean had several autowired fields holding a reference to these repositories, but now I just removed the `@Autowired` annotation and used the constructor to initialize them. The result is a constructor with many arguments that will probably grow in the future as long as I create more repositories/services:

```java
@Bean
public Syncer syncer(SatBackendApplication.AppParamService appParamService,
                     CustomerRepository customerRepository,
                     AddressRepository addressRepository,
                     ContactPersonRepository contactPersonRepository,
                     CustomerContractRepository customerContractRepository,
                     ProductRepository productRepository,
                     OrderRepository orderRepository,
                     OrderRepository.OrderLineRepository orderLineRepository
                     ) {
    return new Syncer(
            appParamService,
            customerRepository,
            addressRepository,
            contactPersonRepository,
            customerContractRepository,
            productRepository,
            orderRepository,
            orderLineRepository);
}
```

Is this the right way to inject dependencies to a bean? Is there any alternative solution with less code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, having constructors with multiple parameters is a consequence of DI. It's a good thing, because you can then create those objects outside of DI (such as in tests) without running into problems such as uninitialized fields.

However, calling those constructors manually *in your production code* is not good. You shouldn't need that `@Bean` method at all, just annotate the `Syncer` class so that Spring can `@Autowire` it for you where you need it.

Also consider that if you need *that many* dependencies, maybe your class is doing too much. See if you can split up its responsibilities into different classes.

Comment: Thank you. I have annotated Syncer as `@Service` with its constructor `@Autowired`, and removed the `@Bean` from the application configuration. On the other hand, Syncer is really doing a lot of stuff. It basically keeps these repositories synced with a third-party application.  The syncer periodically polls the third-party app to update the data in the repos.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Jorn. You can use `Lombok` annotation `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to reduce boilerplate code. It will generate the constructor with all fields declared as final or annotated with `@NonNull`.

Example based on your code:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Syncer {

    private final SatBackendApplication.AppParamService appParamService;
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
// ...
}
```

Please note: if you need more then one constructor then you must add following attribute:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
```